# How to output complete details

Tags: java

I am looking to create a leisure centre booking system in Java, which utilises OOP.

2 of the classes collect names and addresses and membership type, which are added to an ArrayList called memberRegister. How can I print all of the member details (i.e. what is stored in the array list), thus outputting Name, Address, Membertype, etc, all in one command?

My source code for classes in question follows...

```java
public class Name {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    
    //constructor to create object with a first and last name
    public Name(String fName, String lName) {
        
        firstName = fName;
        middleName = "";
        lastName = lName;
    }
    
    //constructor to create object with first, middle and last name
    //if there isn't a middle name, that parameter could be an empty String
    public Name(String fName, String mName, String lName) {
        firstName = fName;
        middleName = mName;
        lastName = lName;
    }
    
    // constructor to create name from full name
    // in the format first name then space then last name
    // or first name then space then middle name then space then last name
    public Name (String fullName) {
        int spacePos1 = fullName.indexOf(' ');
        firstName = fullName.substring(0, spacePos1);
        int spacePos2 = fullName.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if (spacePos1 == spacePos2)
            middleName = "";
        else
            middleName = fullName.substring(spacePos1+1, spacePos2);
        lastName = fullName.substring(spacePos2 + 1);
    }
    
    // returns the first name
    public String getFirstName() {return firstName; }
    // returns the last name
    public String getLastName() {return lastName; }
    
    //change the last name to the value provided in the parameter
    public void setLastName(String ln) {
        lastName = ln;
    }
    
    //returns the first name then a space then the last name
    public String getFirstAndLastName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    
    // returns the last name followed by a comma and a space
    // then the first name
    public String getLastCommaFirst() {
        return lastName + ", "+ firstName;
    }
    
    public String getFullname() {
        return firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;       
        
    }
    
}

public class Address {

    private String first_line, town, postcode;
    
    public Address(String first_line, String town, String pcode)
    {
        this.first_line = first_line;
        this.town = town;
        postcode = pcode;
    }
    
    public Address()
    {
        first_line = "";
        town = "";
        postcode = "";
    }
    
    public String getFirst_line() {
        return first_line;
    }
    
    public void setFirst_line(String first_line) {
        this.first_line = first_line;
    }
    
    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }
    
    public void setTown() {
        this.town = town;
    }
    
    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }
    
    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }
}

public class Member extends Person {
    
    private String id; // membership ID number
    private String type; // full, family, exercise, swim, casual
    
    public Member(String id, String type, Name n, Address a)
    {
        super(n, a);
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
        
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Registration {
    
    private ArrayList<Member> memberRegister;
    
    public Registration()
    {
        memberRegister = new ArrayList();
    }
    
    public void register(Member m)
    {
        memberRegister.add(m);
    }
    
    public int countMembers()
    {
        return memberRegister.size();
    }
    
    public Member getMember(int i) {
        return memberRegister.get(i);
    }

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Name n = new Name("Kieran", "David", "Nock");
        Address a = new Address ("123 Skywalker Way", "London", "NW1 1AA");
        
        Member m = new Member("001", "Full", n, a);
        Registration reg = new Registration();
        reg.register(m);
        
        System.out.println(reg.countMembers());
        System.out.println(reg.getMember(0).getName().getFullname());
 
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a `dumpInformation()` method that outputs all the relevant information.

Comment: @luk2302 Apologies for my noobishness, I am not familiar with how to do that

Comment: There simply is no built-in way for this, you need to write it. And if you do not know how to write it then watch a tutorial on how to write methods...

Comment: @luk2302 Ah right. I was thinking there was a one click solution so to speak lol

Comment: Well, if you override the `toString()` methods of your various classes, you could print the entire contents of your member register with `System.out.println(memberRegister.toString());`.  Aesthetically, however, the result will be less than pleasing, and should be reserved only for debugging/troubleshooting use.  You can do much better by designing an attractive presentation format and writing a specific method to produce that layout.

Comment: Iterate through memberRegister and print out the information for each member.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I would do it in following way

First override `toString()` methods of all the model classes and remember to override Member class `toString()` in following way

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}'+super.toString();
    }
```

After this adding the below single line in main method would work

```
reg.getMemberRegister().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

NOTE: create a getter for `memberRegister` list which is present in `Registration` Class